# Does System.today() change within a single transaction?

Tags: apex, date

I would assume that every call to `System.today()` produces a realtime answer, meaning if you call it at `23:59:59`, it will produce a different answer than if your code runs for another second and calls again at `00:00:00`. But I've also read about compilers that inline system methods to improve performance. Is this the case for Salesforce, and is it then safe to call `System.today()` every time I need it? Or is it best practice to assign any time-based methods to a variable if it needs to be reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly see two different values from `today()` within the same transaction (along the boundary between days). Sometimes that's the behavior you want, and sometimes you want an accurate value each time. It totally depends on the use case. There's no universal answer about which behavior is correct.

As for performance impact, it's pretty minimal. The time it takes to call these methods is on the order of microseconds, so you really don't need to worry about it unless you're calling them millions of times. Even then, they are unlikely to be the biggest bottleneck you can improve.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I'm not necessarily looking to improve performance in my code so much as reduce variable clutter.  Since the performance difference between calling the method and setting/calling a variable is negligible, I would rather just call System.today() multiple times...unless it produces a new value every time, which is what it sounds like it does.

Comment: It does produce a new value each time, but with `today()` there is a minimal chance of divergence. With `now()`, that chance is much higher.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adrian's answer, you should consider isolating your code from testmethods running over a midnight boundary

Every reference to `System.today()` should be replaced by `Util.today`. Then, your testmethods can use

```
Util.today = Date.newInstance(2040,7,1); // use what is approp for the test
```

so that the tests always run with a simulated invariant date.  This includes mocking Sobjects with date or datetime fields

*Caveat: formula fields and VR can't exploit this*

```
//  -----------------------------------------------
//  now     : getter/setter to have testemthod-driven different values for now; see also today
//  -----------------------------------------------
public static DateTime now  {get {return now == null ? DateTime.now() : now;} set;}


//  -----------------------------------------------
//  today       : getter/setter to have testemthod-driven different values for today; see also now
//  -----------------------------------------------
public static Date today {get {return today == null ? Date.today() : today;} set;}
```