# Writing a test class for an invocable method that combines the UTC dates of the beginning of the year and the current time

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method

I built an apex class for an invocable method that runs from a flow to generate a link to authenticate a user to a community. The apex class updates a field on the contact record when the contact (a partner portal user) clicks the flow button and is linked then to a website. The class generates a code from the calculation of midnight at the start of the year, with the current time in GMT/UTC format. It's my first time in a while writing a test class so wanted to gather so insights.

```
  global class PassKeyInvocable {
  @invocableVariable(required=true)
  global List<Contact> contactId;



//Gather the contact record Id from the user record. Just the first and only one.
@InvocableMethod(label='The Users Contact Id' description='Get the users contact id')  
global static void PassKey(List<Id> contactIds) { 
id contactId = contactIds[0];
    
//calculate the passkey (an unique variable the vendor wants) by comparing the current 
date/time with Janurary 1st of the current year in GMT
// STATIC VALUES PROVIDED BY THE VENDOR
Integer Offset = 43994;
Integer Multiplier = 3290;
    
    
//Get the current time zone and establish the time zone offset    

//Get the first day of the year in GMT
DateTime oFirstYear = dateTime.newInstanceGMT(dateTime.now().year(), 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    
    
// get current GMT Time in UTC date/time
DateTime oUTCDate = DateTime.newInstance(
                                            System.now().year(),
                                            System.now().month(),
                                            System.now().day(),
                                            System.now().hour(),
                                            System.now().minute(),
                                            System.now().second());
 

  //get # hours elapsed since the start of the year
  Long firstOfTheYear  = oFirstYear.getTime();
  Long currentDateTime = oUTCDate.getTime();
  Long milliseconds    = currentDateTime - firstOfTheYear;
  Long seconds         = milliseconds/1000;
  Long minutes         = seconds/60;
  Long hours           = minutes/60;

 
Long Calculate = (Offset + hours) * Multiplier;
String Passkey = String.valueOf(calculate);     
  
    //Gather contact Id from the user record (Invocable Flow requires a collection) and just 
        get the first value [0].   
    //Pass the passkey to the user's contact record, which the flow will append to the 
        destination url.
    List<Contact> contactRecord = [Select Id FROM Contact WHERE Id =:contactId]; 
    contact c = contactRecord[0];
    
    c.Passkey__c = Passkey;
    update c;
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: I would also suggest adapting your code to [allow for dependency injection of NOW](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/158209/2602) via a testmethod.  this will make the test more repeatable and not vary based on when executed

Comment: All, got it done by creating a sample contact and calling the apex class in my test which got 100 percent coverage.